# How to allocate program memory and storage before running my application on WinCE?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, windows-ce

I am reprogramming an app in C # to run on Windows CE , however , my machine has low memory.
So I need to allocate the appropriate amount of program memory and storage memory. But I can't allocate it manually at every reboot, then I found the SetSystemMemoryDivision () function .
The allocate code that I've made is basically the following :

```
    public void setmemory()
    {
        //Checks if the memory is correctly allocated 
        while (storage_page != 800)
        {
            //Set the memory to 800 pages of 4096 bytes each ( = 800 * 4kB 3.200Kb )
            storage_page = 800;

            //Writes the seted memory
            SetSystemMemoryDivision(storage_page);

            Thread.Sleep(200);

            //Read system memory
            GetSystemMemoryDivision(ref storage_page, ref ram_page, ref page_size);
        }
    }     
    callmenu();
```

(The function is working , but my app still freezes the machine if I do not manually allocate a acceptable value of memory  before.
How can I ensure that the memory was allocated before running any process that can halt the machine?) Correction below:

I was wrong about the issue. Truly the app run only after my device be connected with a computer and run a Debug through the Visual Studio. Everytime that I reboot the device and try to run my app without debug it on pc, the system halt. Even if I manually allocate the memory. So, it seems like the system is freezing because the program try to allocate more than the available 32MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

The main problem was with the GC of CF 2.0, which was failing to properly manage the collect. 
With an upgrade of NET CF v2.0 to v3.5 both in the machine and in the project, the GC began to properly manage the collect and the application worked perfectly.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help and I hope that I can help someone with similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

That's a difficult challenge.  First, you need to know how much memory your app is going to require to run.  The only way to know that is to test, test and test.  Then add a contingency amount.

Once you've got that number, you can the call `SetSystemMemoryDivision` very early in your app startup, before it starts allocating lots of things on the heap and runs out of memory.  Very early in `static void Main()`, before your call to `Application.Run()` would be the typical candidate location.

If the "amount needed" is unknown, you can always create a background service thread that periodically checks the available memory and re-adjusts the memory division to try to always have space for the GC heap to grow into.  That's more difficult to achieve, but not impossible.

Here's an example timer proc that I use to keep the memory at say 95% of available (it would be stored in `HoldProgramMemoryPercent` as an integer like 95):

```
    private void TimerProc(object state)
    {
        // check and adjust memory
        var total = MemoryManagement.SystemProgramMemory + MemoryManagement.SystemStorageMemory;

        var before = (MemoryManagement.SystemProgramMemory / (float)total) * 100;

        var requiredStorage = (int)(((100 - HoldProgramMemoryPercent) / 100f) * total);
        if ((requiredStorage != m_lastLevel) && (requiredStorage != MemoryManagement.SystemStorageMemory))
        {
            MemoryManagement.SystemStorageMemory = requiredStorage;

            var after = (MemoryManagement.SystemProgramMemory / (float)total) * 100;

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Program memory changed from {0}% to {1}%", before, after));

            m_lastLevel = requiredStorage;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Memory load is at {0}%", MemoryManagement.MemoryLoad));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, ctacke.    
I've moved the function to the Program class, in the 'static void Main()', before the 'Application.Run()', but it still not running.     
The automatic allocation like the example should run after the first set, right?

Comment: In this case it may be that the current application memory size in your system is too small to load the .NET CF runtime. Did you try to run a simple "hello world" app instead of your full-application? Does it work? If it does then the only thing I can imagine is that you have some global objects (that are initialized before you enter Main) that allocate a big amount of memory on startup. You can simply try to allocate them in Main, after the call to SetSystemMemoryDivision instead of declaring and initializing them as globals.

Comment: Thanks, Valter.
Smaller applications run well, but I don't initialize any object before the SetSystemMemoryDivision. The only calls before running this function are the DLLs and necessary variables.  
I've tried different amounts of memory allocation, but none of them work.

Comment: And it's important to observe that if I allocate the same memory amount manually, it works well.

Comment: If it works manually, but not programmatically, then your API call is probably failing. You should be able to create an app that just sets the memory division, run the app, then go to the control panel and the division slider should have moved.  Based on the docs, you call (which you aren't checking the return value at all for) returns `SYSMEM_CHANGED` when successful.

Comment: I was wrong about the issue. Truly the app run only after my device be connected with a computer and run a Debug through the Visual Studio. Everytime that I reboot the device and try to run my app without debug it on pc, the system halt. Even if I manually allocate the memory. So, it seems like the system is freezing because the program try to allocate more than the available 32MB.

Answer (score 0):

Use to this code. 
int value ratio as a parameter memory

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static extern int GetSystemMemoryDivision(ref int lpdwStorePages, ref int ldpwRamPages, ref int ldpwPageSize);
        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private static extern int SetSystemMemoryDivision(int dwStorePages);
 public static void SetMemory(int division)
        {
            int storePages = 0;
            int ramPages = 0;
            int pageSize = 0;
            int totalPages = 0;
            if (GetSystemMemoryDivision(ref storePages, ref ramPages, ref pageSize) == 1)
            {
                totalPages = storePages + ramPages;
                storePages = Convert.ToInt32(totalPages * (100 - division) / 100);
                SetSystemMemoryDivision(storePages);
            }
        }
```